# Angular grpc client tells url scheme unsupported,is anyone can solve this?

Tags: angular, typescript, grpc, grpc-web

[this is error printed in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRniE.png)
i create the ts grpc generated file by using grpc-gen-ts then i create the client from the pb_service file, but i invoke the client call this is will the error show up here.

```
 const client = new ServiceClient("localhost:8083")
    const req = new Request()
    client.listCredentials(req, (error, respose) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error)
      } else {
        console.log(respose)
      }
    })
```

this is my invoke method,

why this error coming in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`. Maybe you need to add a protocol: `html://` or `https://`.